# How to remove decorated object from Decorator Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

How could I remove items that have been added using the decorator design pattern? For example Pizza Ordering System. I want to be able delete some items and decrease price.

```
public interface Pizza {
    double getPrice();
}
public class SimplePizza implements Pizza {

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return 25;
    }
}
public abstract class PizzaDecorator implements Pizza {
   Pizza tempPizza;
   public PizzaDecorator(Pizza a){
       tempPizza = a;
   }
   @Override
   public double getPrice(){
       return tempPizza.getPrice();
   }
}
public class Mushroom extends PizzaDecorator {
    public Mushroom(Pizza newPizza){
        super(newPizza);
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return tempPizza.getPrice() + 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a NoMushroomDecorator, which subtracts 10 to the price of a pizza?

Comment: @JBNizet I have 20 items to decorate Should I do that for all of them?

Comment: I think to remove a decorator, you should iterate (loop) through the list of decorators, and build a new Pizza, omitting the items you want to remove..

Comment: You should do what needs to be done for what you want to achieve. If you want to allow removing mushrooms, you add a NoMushroomDecorator. if not, you don't. I would personally not use the decorator pattern to represent toppings on a pizza. I would simply use a Set<Topping>, where you can add or remove toppings.

Comment: @JBNizet I have to do with design patterns It is my homework :)

Comment: @markspace can you show through code ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way to do like this:

```
 interface Pizza {
    double getPrice();
    public abstract Pizza removeItem();
}
 class SimplePizza implements Pizza {

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return 25;
    }
    @Override
    public Pizza removeItem(){
     return null;
    }
}
 abstract class PizzaDecorator implements Pizza {
   Pizza tempPizza;
   public PizzaDecorator(Pizza a){
       tempPizza = a;
   }
   @Override
   public double getPrice(){
       return tempPizza.getPrice();
   }
   public abstract Pizza removeItem();
   }

    class Mushroom extends PizzaDecorator {
    public Mushroom(Pizza newPizza){
        super(newPizza);
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return tempPizza.getPrice()+10;
    }
    @Override
    public Pizza removeItem(){
     return tempPizza;
    }

    }


     class Onion extends PizzaDecorator {
    public Onion(Pizza newPizza){
        super(newPizza);
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return tempPizza.getPrice()+20;
    }

    @Override
    public Pizza removeItem(){
     return tempPizza;
    }
}

public class Main{


public static void main(String args[]){


        Pizza pizza = new SimplePizza(); 

        // create new FarmHouse pizza 
        Pizza pizza2 = new Mushroom(pizza); 


        System.out.println(pizza2.getPrice());//Prints 35.0
         pizza2 = new Onion(pizza2); 



         System.out.println(pizza2.getPrice());////Prints 55.0

       pizza2 = pizza2.removeItem();
         System.out.println(pizza2.getPrice());//Print 35.0



}


}
```

Comment: but this method always deletes the most recent item. I want to delete any of item..

Comment: Yes this solution has such restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through decorators and chain together the decorators before and after the decorator you want to remove, like a linked list:

```
    class Coffee implements ICoffee {
        @Override
        public String ingredients() {
        return "coffee";
        }

        @Override
        public <T> ICoffee removeDecorator(Class<T> decorator) {
            System.out.println("This object has no decorators!");
            return this;
        }
    }

    abstract class CoffeeDecorator implements ICoffee {
        public ICoffee coffee;
        CoffeeDecorator(ICoffee k) {coffee = k;}

        @Override
        public String ingredients() {
            return coffee.ingredients();
        }

        public <T> ICoffee removeDecorator(Class<T> decorator) {
            CoffeeDecorator temp = this;
            if (getClass() == decorator) {
                return coffee;
            }
            while (decorator != temp.coffee.getClass() && temp.coffee.getClass() != Coffee.class) {
                temp = (CoffeeDecorator) temp.coffee;
            }
            if (temp.coffee.getClass() == Coffee.class) {
                System.out.println("Object not decorated with " + decorator);
                return this;
            }
            CoffeeDecorator nextDecorator = (CoffeeDecorator) temp.coffee;
            temp.coffee = nextDecorator.coffee;
            return this;
        }
    }

    class WithSyrup extends CoffeeDecorator {
        WithSyrup(ICoffee k) {
            super(k);
        }

        @Override
        public String ingredients() {
            return super.ingredients() + ", syrup";
        }
    }

    class WithMilk extends CoffeeDecorator {
        WithMilk(ICoffee k) {
            super(k);
        }

        @Override
        public String ingredients() {
            return super.ingredients() + ", milk";
        }
    }

    class WithSugar extends CoffeeDecorator {
        WithSugar(ICoffee k) {
            super(k);
        }

        @Override
        public String ingredients() {
            return super.ingredients() + ", sugar";
        }
    }

    class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ICoffee k = new Coffee();
            k = new WithSyrup(k);
            k = new WithSugar(k);
            k = new WithMilk(k);

            System.out.println(k.ingredients());
            k = k.removeDecorator(WithMilk.class);
            k = k.removeDecorator(WithSyrup.class);
            System.out.println(k.ingredients());
        }

    }
```